# How to add a column to a dataframe that increments based on another column - python

Tags: python

I am trying to add a variable "n" to my dataframe (python) that increments based on another column values. I have more variables, but imagine this is what I have:

```
id    X     
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     4
2     5
3     6
3     7
```

And this is what I want - a variable n that increments based on repeated id, and starts again when the id changes:

```
id    X     n   
1     1     1
1     2     2
1     3     3
2     4     1
2     5     2
3     6     1
3     7     2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) -

The idea is to use `groupby` with `cumcount` which resets the count based on every groupset

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> 
>>> d = {'id':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3],'X':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
   id  X
0   1  1
1   1  2
2   1  3
3   2  4
4   2  5
5   3  6
6   3  7
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> df['n'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount()+1
>>> df
   id  X  n
0   1  1  1
1   1  2  2
2   1  3  3
3   2  4  1
4   2  5  2
5   3  6  1
6   3  7  2
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed! :)

Comment: If it helped you , upvote the answer as well